# How to sum up specific multiple data type JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I tried to sum the value from my array. In this case the output must be `2868`, but my `alert` is still `0`.

```
var data = [{
      name: 'try1',
      y: 1756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try2',
      y: 756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try3',
      y: 356,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }]

var dataSum = 0;
for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
    dataSum += data.y[i]
}

alert(dataSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `data[i].y` and not `data.y[i]` as `data` is your array of object and looping through the `data` will give you each object in `data[i]` then access the property `y` from `data[i]` object.

```js
var data = [{
      name: 'try1',
      y: 1756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try2',
      y: 756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try3',
      y: 356,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }]

var dataSum = 0;
for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
    dataSum += data[i].y
}

alert(dataSum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dataSum += data.y[i]
```

should be

```
dataSum += data[i].y
```

You are iterating `data`, not `data.y`

Answer (score 1):

You have to sum the number of property `y` from appropriate index (position).

So change `data.y[i]` To `data[i].y`

```js
var data = [{
      name: 'try1',
      y: 1756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try2',
      y: 756,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    },{
      name: 'try3',
      y: 356,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
    }]

var dataSum = 0;
for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
    dataSum += data[i].y
}

alert(dataSum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[i]` in your `data.y[i]` is incorrectly placed.
This should be `data[i].y`

your array of object is `data`, so you must put the `[i]` in your `data` and not in your `y`

```js
var data = [{
  name: 'try1',
  y: 1756,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
},{
  name: 'try2',
  y: 756,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
},{
  name: 'try3',
  y: 356,
  fontWeight: 'bold',
}];

var dataSum = 0;
for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
    dataSum += data[i].y
}

alert(dataSum);
```